# Should I override clean or validate_unique? What's the difference?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

What is the difference if in **models.py** I had:

```
def validate_unique(self, exclude=None):
    qs = KeyDefinition.objects.filter(key_name=self.key_name, developer_email=self.developer_email)
    print(qs)
    if qs:
        raise ValidationError (
             {'key_name' : ['This Key Name already exists']} 
        )
    return super().validate_unique(exclude)
```

vs:

```
def clean(self):
    qs = KeyDefinition.objects.filter(key_name=self.key_name, developer_email=self.developer_email)
    print(qs)
    if qs:
        raise ValidationError (
             {'key_name' : ['This Key Name already exists']} 
        )
```

These seem to have no difference in the outcome.

Basically, I want to make sure that each developer can't submit a key with the same name as one they already have (but two developers can have a key with the same name).

I have handled this at the database level by using the `unique_together` option in the `Meta` class.

Answer (score 0):

The difference is that `clean` is a form method and is only called when you are validating the form. If you are creating a model object without a form then obviously that code won't be run. If you are using `validate_unique` then it should be run whether a form is used or not.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. However, say if I don't use a form and use "validate_unique", then is there any point in using the "unique_together" aswell? Considering my "validate_unique" function will raise a ValidationError anyway?

Comment: No, it shouldn't be necessary as your `unique_together` should handle it - I guess it doesn't hurt to have another function to check it, but it would be redundant

Comment: Wait, if both methods are defined in models.py then are you sure "clean" is a form method and is only called when validating the form.. ?

Comment: iirc you need to override `save()` to call `clean()`, it's not done automatically. Clean is always called on a form though